# Python Pandas groupby closely spaced events

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find an efficient way to group closely spaced events together. If I have the time series generated by:

```
In [247]: times = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='M')
In [248]: times = times[(times < times[20]) | (times > times[40])]
```

So that I have 2 groups of events separated by 1 month each with a long gap in between. Is there a efficient way to find these groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `diff()` method and a threshold to calculate the groupby array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='M')
times = times[(times < times[20]) | (times > times[40])]

s = pd.DataFrame({"value":np.random.rand(len(times)), "times":times})
g = (s.times.diff() > np.timedelta64(60, "D")).astype(int).cumsum()
print s.groupby(g).min()
```

output:

```
                times     value
0 2011-01-31 00:00:00  0.022073
1 2014-06-30 00:00:00  0.003856
```

Comment: Oh, I really like that solution. I was doing something similar, where I added a diff column, set the values to 0 if it was below my cut, and then `cumsum`ed that. I like making a grouping series as a one shot a lot better.